# Record with blank field not visible after using filter

Tags: ms-access, vba

II MAKE MAKING A ACCESS DATABASE.I  have a form with a subform and few combo box to use as a filter the data. when there is a blank field in the table it is not shown my coding for the filter is

```
Function searchcriteria()
Dim device, vlan As String
Dim task, strciteria As String


If IsNull(Me.cbodevice) Then
device = "[DEVICE NAME] like '*'"
Else
device = "[DEVICE NAME]= '" & Me.cbodevice & "'"
End If


If IsNull(Me.cbovlan) Then
vlan = "[VLAN ID] like '*'"
Else
vlan = "[VLAN ID]= '" & Me.cbovlan & "'"
End If
strcriteria = device & "And" & vlan
task = "select * from L2PORTDETAILS where " & strcriteria
Me.L2PORTDETAILS_subform.Form.RecordSource = task
Me.L2PORTDETAILS_subform.Form.Requery


End Function]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler just to set the Filter property:

```
Function SearchCriteria()

    ' Preset Me!L2PORTDETAILS_subform.Form.RecordSource to:
    ' "select * from L2PORTDETAILS"

    Dim Filter As String

    If Not IsNull(Me!cbodevice.Value) Then
        Filter = "[DEVICE NAME]= '" & Me!cbodevice.Value & "'"
    End If       
    If Not IsNull(Me!cbovlan.Value) Then
        If Filter <> "" Then
            Filter = Filter & " And "
        End If
        Filter = Filter & "[VLAN ID] = '" & Me!cbovlan.Value & "'"
    End If
    With Me!L2PORTDETAILS_subform.Form
        .Filter = Filter
        .FilterOn = (Filter <> "")
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Dear Gustav   where to write this code is it a function search criteria ,i m new to vba kindly explain it please .what u mean by filter property.

Comment: Write it where you already have the previous code. The Filter property is a property of the form. Study the on-line help or browse for other examples.

Comment: dear i am sory to ask u again.where is recor source ? and if i have more then two filter will it work

Comment: RecordSource is another property of the subform (tab Data). Yes, the code as shown will respect either or both filter values. But it sounds like you really need to study a tutorial (free for the browsing) to get your feet going.

Comment: i replaced my posted code with this code but it is not working kindly help  me thnaks

Comment: "Not working" isn't very useful. Many things may need adjustment.